# How to call function with event from useEffect

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, use-effect

I have `<form>` with `handleSubmit`.

How do I call `handleSubmit` function with `event` from my `useEffect`?

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (searchFromUrl) {
      handleSubmit();
    }
  }, []);

  const handleSubmit = async (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault();
}

<form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className="flex relative search-form"></form>
```

this is my error

```
 const handleSubmit: (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => Promise<void>
    Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.ts(2554)
    SearchBox.tsx(27, 31): An argument for 'e' was not provided.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're calling `handleSubmit();` without having the `e` event variable.

if you truly want to call it in `useEffect`, then change `e` argument to optional:

```
const handleSubmit = async (e?: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
  if (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
  // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
useEffect(() => {
    if (searchFromUrl) {
      handleSubmit(e); // u need to provide 'e'
    }
}, []);

const handleSubmit = async (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault();
}

<form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className="flex relative search-form"></form>
```

Comment: Yes, mate, thats what i dont know how to do :D

Comment: 'e' is automatically get passed when u pass ur `handleSubmit` function to 'onSubmit'  attribute of the form, thats why u need to mention 'e' as function param in `handleSubmit` i.e `handleSubmit(e)`, whenever, wherever u call it